# How to add Django statements to Javascript

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement some JS code in django so anytime i click a button, it returns the current year.. how do i do this

I've tried using some JS events handler in my django based templates

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.http import HttpResponse as toHTML

cont = Context({'dat':datetime.now()})
def say_year(request):
 htm = Template("<button onclick='alert({dat})'>click me</button>")
 htm = htm.render(cont)
 return toHTML(htm)
```

i'm expecting an alert box showing full datetime.now() methods

Answer (score 1):

I prefer that you do it that way in order to have full control over the template.
1 - make the views.py that way :

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.shortcuts import render

def say_year(request):
    context = {
    'dat': datetime.now()
    }
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context)
```

2- The urls.py should look that way :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from your_app import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('my_template/', views.say_year )
]
```

3- You create a templates folder in the root directory of your project where all your templates will live.
For your question i have create my_template.html and it should be that way :

```
<button onclick="alert('{{dat}}')">click me</button>
```

If you have more questions please let me know.